# Using classes in static main method

Tags: java, static, program-entry-point

So I'm writing a mini-board game program in Java.

The program is going to read in standard input and construct a game as directed in the input.

To help stay organized and progress my oo java skills, I am using a Cell class to act as a cell in a nxn game.

For the board game, I need to have it all in one file, and it must run from static void main.

Here's what my Cell class looks like

```
public class Cell{
      public int x;
      public int y;
      .
      .
      .
 }
```

I want to read the input, and assign values to each cell and then add the cells to a list such as ArrayList allCells. However, I can not the use it in a static context.

I understand that static is a single instance, so I'm confused how I would go about doing this. Is there anyway I can use a class-based system to solve this problem. Each cell is it's own individual object, so making it stat wouldn't work.

Any sort-of explanation or alternative would be amazing! Hope I was clear enough in my description.

Comment: Would there be anything wrong with instantiating the `Cell` class, e.g. `Cell cell = new Cell(3, 0);` ?

Comment: The main method is there just to give your program an entry point, usually to create a main master class object and perhaps some subsidiary objects, and then set them going. Don't focus on the main method. First focus on the "nouns" of your project. Yes a Cell class is great, but what are you going to put it in? A Grid class perhaps, and what object will run the logic of the program? And what object(s) will interact with the user....

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm a little confused about your question. When parsing over the input, I try to put each piece of information in a cell like that but it can't since it's being called from a static context

Comment: `"For the board game, I need to have it all in one file."` -- why? What's the rationale for this requirement?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I have a Game class, similar to what you're describing as a Grid class and it is static. The only problem is that there is a lot of information to put into it. The Cell class was to organize pieces of information together for each cell. I don't want to ignore the main method, because if I get it to function and can't get it to work with main then it was pointless.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels not my rationale, to regulate it i guess

Comment: `"not my rationale, to regulate it i guess"` -- explain please. If not your rationale, then whose? If your it is your instructor's, then please post the exact wording of the requirement, because you may be misinterpreting it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't think I'm misunderstanding it, it's pretty straight forward lol "single java file, game.java. Within this java file, you must include a public static function, main()"

Comment: "You may include any other helper methods or
classes within this single file as you see fit."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would be to make `Cell` a top-level class in its own file, but you've indicated that you need everything in a single file. So I'll answer with that constraint in mind.

You need to declare the `Cell` class itself to be `static` in order to use it in a static context. For instance:

```
public class Game {
    public static class Cell { // doesn't really need to be public
        ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cell c1 = new Cell();
        Cell c2 = new Cell();
        ...
    }
}
```

Without the `static` modifier for the `Cell` class, you will get a compiler error when calling `new Cell()` inside `main()` (which I'm guessing is basically the problem you are having).

An alternative is to modify the `Cell` class to be non-`public`. Then you can make it a top-level class in the same file as your game class:

```
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cell c1 = new Cell();
        Cell c2 = new Cell();
        ...
    }
}

class Cell {
    ...
}
```

Yet another alternative would be to make `Cell` a local class in the `main()` method:

```
public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        class Cell {
            ...
        }
        Cell c1 = new Cell();
        Cell c2 = new Cell();
        ...
    }
}
```

However, then you would only be able to use the `Cell` class in the `main()` method itself; you could not take advantage of the `Cell` structure in any other methods of your game.

Comment: Why recommend that he make it static? Wouldn't it be much cleaner to leave it a stand alone class in its own file?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - OP said that everything needed to be in a single file. Perhaps this is an assignment and that's part of the specs.

Comment: How could the cell class be static? Doesn't than mean there is only one instance? There needs to be multiple cells for the various coordinates

Comment: I do need to access the Cell class in helper methods to perform evaluations

Comment: @Joseph - Declaring the `Cell` class as `static` does not mean there's only one instance of `Cell`; that only applies to member fields of a class. When a nested class is _not_ declared `static` then it is an _inner class_ and cannot be instantiated from a `static` context: it needs an instance of the outer class to provide context. See the [Java tutorial on nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for mroe details.

Comment: @TedHopp Wow thanks, that was what I was confused with. I was under the impression that it applied to classes. Simple fix, thank you